# ASP.net FileHelpers failed to convert string to datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, filehelpers

I work on this issue since almost 2 days. Here is the error message:

> FileHelpers.ConvertException: 'Error Converting '8/8/2018 8:48:52 AM'
>   to type: 'DateTime'.  There are less chars in the Input String than in
>   the Format string: 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt''

I tried a lot of things and it does not work. Tried `'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt'`

Tried to put directly in the class like this:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")]
```

Tried almost all possible date formats I could find on here and on google.

Im strugelling with this since almost 2 days.

Please help!

[Print screen running step by step with value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZD7z.png)

Thank you,

Comment: use [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")]

Comment: as of now i don't know, what are you and where are you doing this stuff so this is my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for replying!! I tried that already. and much more different format. Thank you!!

Comment: okay then please share some more scenario with detailed code and snaps so that it can help us to understand.

Comment: also review the peer i have edited for your question. I will look better and catch more response.

Comment: You can straight try this: PotStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact("8/8/2018 8:48:52 AM", "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) with any format I found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN . But it does not work. I will have a look to solution of Marwen... but still the format needs to include the datetime... but it gaves me idea. And thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
```

the "U" displays Thursday, April 10, 2008 1:30:00 PM from this code

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("U", 
              CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

You can check all the supported format strings [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

and try this :

```
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy" )]
```

Comment: Its good idea to just cut my string and recreate a new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0); I am trying it now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow! There was a null in my table which was suppose to be impossible... Well this how it is!! the parse works just fine!!!